# Calling on a property of an entity's parent in a relationship

Tags: xcode, core-data, entity-relationship, cocoa-bindings

I have an `NSColumnItem` Selected Value bound to a relationship property (**jobParent**) in an entity (**jobs**). This is an inverse relationship to a property (**projectChild**) in a separate entity (**projects**).

How do I call on the **projectTitle** property of my **projects** entity to display in my `NSTableColumn`, based on the relationship to the currently selected **jobTitle** (from my **jobs** entity) in my `NSTableView`? I tried entering `jobParent.projectTitle` for the `Model Key Path` and `arrangedObjects` for the `Controller Key` but it's not working (as well as any other combination I can think of). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to make sure the related entity is bound to '`content set`' and then address the properties of the related table by using a period after the relationship property of the child entity followed by the property you want of the parent entity. For my example above, to get the **projectTitle** property of my **projects** entity in relation to my **jobs** entity, I would call on:

```
jobParent.projectTitle
```